# What action hook updates post meta?

Tags: post-meta, wp-update-post

Is there an straight-forward example anywhere of using [wp_update_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to edit post_meta on the front end? I have not been able to find any good learning resources.

What I want to do is display post meta in an input field and when a user clicks *submit* trigger `wp_update_post();`.

[image: post meta in input field with save button]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_update_post` isn't used for updating custom fields (ie postmeta content) - you should use [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: it's `update_post_meta` ;)

Comment: @thedeadmedic - doh! annoying inconsistent WP function naming conventions. Corrected - thanks.