# Front-end update_post_meta snippet displays white screen?

Tags: post-meta

Thanks to @Anu's [correction](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/wp-update-post-example) I now have a function to update_post_meta from the front end.

Something is wrong in my script however, because with the function below nothing is being displayed on the page. It only displays is a white screen. if I take out the `if ( empty($_POST) ||` section the page template will display, but any changes I make to the form are not saving.

What am I missing?

```
// top of page
if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['name_of_nonce_field'],'name_of_my_action') )
    { //if fail nonce check, exit script
       exit;
    }
else :
    {
    global $post;
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $data = $_POST['priceone'];
    update_post_meta($postid,'metakey',$data);
    }
endif;

// in single.php
$priceone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'priceone', true);
<form method="post" action="">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('update_drw_postmeta','drw_inventory'); ?>
   <label>This is label</label>
   <input type='text' name='priceone' value='<?php echo $priceone ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your nonce verify to actually verify and update post meta, else do nothing. But don't use exit at the top of your template.

```
// top of page
if ( isset( $_POST['drw_inventory'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['drw_inventory'],'update_drw_postmeta') )
    { //if nonce check succeeds.
        global $post;
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $data = $_POST['priceone'];
        update_post_meta($postid,'metakey',$data);
    }

// in single.php
$priceone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'priceone', true);
<form method="post" action="">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('update_drw_postmeta','drw_inventory'); ?>
   <label>This is label</label>
   <input type='text' name='priceone' value='<?php echo $priceone ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

Comment: the if syntax is missing a ) or a , ... Does this look correct to you? `if ( isset( $_POST['drw_inventory'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['drw_inventory'],'update_drw_postmeta') )`

Comment: my bad, fixed it.