# Use ajax to update_post_meta

Tags: php, custom-field, ajax, mysql, post-meta

2 days ago I asked [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59518/front-end-update-post-meta-with-ajax?rq=1) then I tried to work on my code to be able to understand how ajax and php work and now I have a new issue that, probably would be easily solved.

These are my codes:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Nuovo form
*/
?>
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
<?php wp_head();?>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/nuovoform/comment.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then this is my Comment.php

```
<?php 
// This is comment.php content
$nuovoform = 0;
$nuovocommento = 1;
if ( isset( $_POST['name'] )){
$nuovoform = $_POST['name'];}
if ( isset( $_POST['comment'] )){
$nuovocommento = $_POST['comment'];}
update_post_meta($post->ID,'varcontrollo',$nuovoform);
$controlliamo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'varcontrollo', true);
?>
```

'varcontrollo' is a custom meta field created using Custom Field Template plugin.

What I'm trying to do is use the form I created to store the result inside my custom field.
If I try to browse to comment.php it says this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function update_post_meta() in
>   D:\Locali\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\slotlandia\nuovoform\comment.php
>   on line 8

Probably i have to 'import' WordPress 'global' variables but I don't know what have I to write.

Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to get an idea how to code a wordpress theme. Do a google search and follow a tutorial. I think then you will know most of the basics about how create and wordpress template files. Fatal error says you don't have any function named `update_meta_data()`

Comment: I have never had this kind of issues and I am usually able to code a custom template.
Only this time I'm having problems so a good answer would be more helpfull instead of an useless comment...
I now what Fatal Error means but I can't understand why update_meta_data() is not recognized.
I tought that update_meta_data() was a 'core' function of Wordpress with no need to redeclare it each time.

Comment: There is no function `update_meta_data()` in WordPress.

Comment: @toscho yes you are right, I was wrong the correct function is: update_post_meta
Anyway I have the same problem even after using: update_post_meta

Comment: [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56343/template-issues-getting-ajax-search-results/) is a similar issue, answer is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will not work because you are referring to a single php file, instead the the whole WordPress environment.

There's a easier way to use ajax in WordPress.

Use `admin_url('admin-ajax')` as the form action, then put the function that will answer the ajax call in the theme's functions.php.

More detail here in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-to-handle-form-submission/60766#60766)