# How to handle form submission?

Tags: forms

I'm new to wordpress and hence facing some issues.

**The use case scenario is as follows:**

1. A user is displayed an application form to start a club in his school.
2. The user fills the form and hits the 'Submit' button.
3. The form needs to be validated.
4. If the validation is successful, then data is stored in custom table `club_details` in db and the user is shown some message(eg: Thanks for submission. Your application is sent to the admin for approval.)  else appropriate error messages are shown to the user.
5. The admin goes to the Wordpress admin panel to approve the pending requests for the club. (The data is fetched from db and shown to the admin).

**I have done the following:**

- for 1) I have created a application form/page using the Wordpress HTML editor.
- for 3) I have a javascript file (`validation.js`) that has the validation code.
- for 4) I have a php file (`club-functions.php`) that has a function `storeInDB()` to store the application details in custom table in db.
- for 5) I have created my own plugin folder and added a php file (`club.php`) that displays the application details to the admin on the Wordpress admin panel.

I'm stuck up at the following place: How to handle the form submission. Where should I place the code that calls the javascript's validate function and later calls the `storeInDB()` function.

Please provide me some suggestions on how do I achieve this and is this approach good?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 16):

You should use the `wp_ajax` or the `wp_ajax_nopriv` function.

First of all you should put the the admin ajax url as the action attribute value in the submission form.

```
<form id="" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" class="form" >
```

That way the the form will be submitted to the admin-ajax.php by default (without JavaScript). You can use JavaScript to make it work using AJAX.

Next is the function that will use the submitted data. Inside the form, put a `wp_nonce_field` and a hidden input with the name action. My action value is `add_transfer`.

```
<?php wp_nonce_field('add_transfer','security-code-here'); ?>
<input name="action" value="add_transfer" type="hidden">
```

You can put the function that will handle this form in the functions.php or in your plugin file. You can use `wp_ajax_` + the action name if this is a form only for logged in users. For non logged in users, use `wp_ajax_nopriv` + the action name instead.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_transfer', 'process_add_transfer');

function process_add_transfer() {
    if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['security-code-here'],'add_transfer') ) {
        echo 'You targeted the right function, but sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
        die();
    } else {
        // do your function here 
        wp_redirect($redirect_url_for_non_ajax_request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ifdion for the reply. I'm creating the form in 'Wordpress HTML editor'. So, is it good to include php code in the form as I will have to install 'Exec-PHP' plugin which I believe is a overkill? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Just replace the action value with http://your-site-url.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Does that work?

Comment: is there a good way to achieve the same but without admin-ajax.php?

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but this won't work as `wp_redirect` won't do anything here; AJAX requests run in the background and `wp_redirect` is just a smart wrapper for a `header('location:...')` call that needs to be run prior to output. If you want a redirect following an AJAX call, you need to pass back a URL and handle the redirect via JS. For reference: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133939/17826

Comment: @indextwo thanks for the comment. You are right, you do need a proper URL to be passed back and then redirected to via JS, for an AJAX request. The `wp_redirect` also will be of no use in an AJAX request. But my answer isn't using any JS therefore it isn't an AJAX request, though it utilize the `wp_ajax` and the `wp_ajax_nopriv` functions. The `wp_redirect` is used to send the user away from the blank `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` page. Hope this clears thing out.

Comment: 'admin-ajax.php' → where is this file residing? I mean in which folder?

Comment: @TheWPNovice I guess it is still in the ``/wp-admin/`` directory. Note that you don't need to change or add anything in that file.

Comment: Can this system also work on a form that is trying to send email?

Answer (score 2):

first, let me tell you that javascript validation works on client side. so if the user, disables js, you're going to have problems.

so, you should also validate the input values, server-side.

with that in mind:

The js code can be called directly from the page where the form is. onsubmit attribute is the usual way to call it.

**example**

```
<form onSubmit="validateForms()" method="post" action="domain.com/club-contacts">
    <label for="app_email">Application</label>
    <input type="text" name="app_email" id="app_email" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="app_application" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="app_form_send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

## page.php

This can be also your custom template page or single.php. in this case, 99 is the ID of the specific page you want to indicate to the user if it was approved or had an error.

```
if ( get_the_ID() == '99' ) {
  // lets validate the input
  if( !empty($_POST['app_application']) && $_POST['app_application'] == "1"  ) {
   if(!empty($_POST['app_email'])) {
    // check the codex for [Data_Validation][1]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks peteroak for the reply. Where can I call PHP code to further process the form data?

Comment: the action attribute will point to a file. in that file you can filter and validate your form. i will update my response to include that.