# redirect does not work in ajax function

Tags: theme-development, ajax, redirect, wp-redirect

I'm using ajax to post the form data. In the end I want to redirect to homepage. I'm trying following code, it does not work. It returns error 302.
How can I redirect in the following function? Thanks.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_register', 'custom_register');
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_register', 'custom_register');

function custom_register(){

    //process

    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The AJAX request runs in the background. Redirects here do not affect the main page. And 302 is not an error, it is just a status code.

Your AJAX response should return either the URL and the status code to the calling page or just a number like 1. Then you handle the redirect in the calling page:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var url = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>';
    $( '#ajaxtrigger' ).on( 'click',
        function() {
            $.post( ajaxurl, {}, function( response ) {
                if ( 1 == response )
                    top.location.replace(url);
            });
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's some years behind but I think this answer can help others:

I have used a function to redirect from a JS AJAX call. First, it sets some values to database and then tries to redirect in this way:

```
if (wp_safe_redirect( $url))

    exit();
```

But it just returns same page followed by 'undefined'.

I finally solved directly the redirection part in JS:

```
window.location.href = url; // keeps page history
```

Works also :

```
window.location.replace( url ); // cleans page history
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to redirect then use javascript `window.lcation="your url"` in your php code.

Try this in your function that is called by the ajax call;

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_register', 'custom_register');
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_register', 'custom_register');

function custom_register(){

    //process

    $url = home_url(); 

    ?>
       <script>

        demo(); //function name of jscript

        function demo()
        {
            window.location="<?php echo $url ?>";
        }

       </script>

    <?php exit;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?