# Handling form actions in Wordpress

Tags: php, functions

A non wordpress PHP file has this kind of code:

```
<form class="someclass" action="page-contact.php" method="post">
```

But when in WordPress it doesn’t work.

suppose we are here(a WordPress page or a post):
www.sample.com/somepage/

The above page is using the page-contact.php template.

Then the above when the to submit button of the contact form is triggered takes to:

www.sample.com/somepage/page-contact.php

This generates an error that 404 not found(because that link doesn’t exist). what is the solution so that it(action) works in WordPress?

I tried the solution posted here → 
[How to handle form submission?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-to-handle-form-submission)

1. But that solution doesn't work.
2. Even if had worked than which theme author will put an action file in wp-admin because the path is shown their belongs to wp-admin →

action=`"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"`

In my case, the admin-ajax.php file will be the same template/page file where the swiftmailer code is there with SMTP settings to send an email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle form submission?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-to-handle-form-submission)

Comment: That solution won't work. I have updated the reason there.

Comment: Do you send your form via Ajax?

Comment: I think that would be an another solution. isn't it?