# Front end update_post_meta Help

Tags: forms, front-end, save-post, post-meta

I followed the help provided in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21503/front-end-update-post-meta-snippet-displays-white-screen) question but cannot get the form save the data. I tried using 'save_post' action hook to try and save the post like we do for admin side. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My code is as below:

/* This is above the get_header() of the template */

```
if ( isset( $_POST['grn_data'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['grn_data'],'update_grn_postmeta') )
{ //if nonce check succeeds.
    global $post;
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $data = $_POST['grn'];
    update_post_meta($postid,'grn',$data);
}
```

And the form is in a seperate file and i am calling it whenever it is necessary.

```
<?php
/* This file is to provide input fields to record data from Front End */
function grn_data($c) {
        global $post;
        $grn = array();
?>
        <div class="grndata">
        <label for="grn" id="grnhead">GRN</label>
        <div class="toggle-fedata">
        <ul>
        <?php
        $curgrn = 'grn';
        $grnval = get_post_meta($post->ID, $curgrn, true); ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('update_grn_data','grn_data'); ?>
        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name="<?php echo $curgrn; ?>" value="<?php echo $grnval; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <?php var_dump($grnval); ?>
        <?php var_dump($curgrn); ?>
        </form>
        </div></div>
<?php }

?>
```

Please can someone advise on this? I have been stuck like this for days now.

Answer (score 1):

your nonce action name is wrong use same as entered in `wp_nonce_field('update_grn_data','grn_data');` and also you forget to echo nonce, try this

```
if ( isset( $_POST['grn_data'] ) &&  wp_verify_nonce($_POST['grn_data'],'update_grn_data') ) {
    //if nonce check succeeds.
    $postid = $_POST['post_id'];
    $data = $_POST['grn'];
    update_post_meta($postid,'grn',$data);
}
```

form

```
<?php
/* This file is to provide input fields to record data from Front End */
function grn_data($post_id) { ?>
    <div class="grndata">
        <label for="grn" id="grnhead">GRN</label>
        <div class="toggle-fedata">
           <?php
           $curgrn = 'grn';
           $grnval = get_post_meta($post_id, $curgrn, true); ?>
           <form method="post" action="">
              <?php echo wp_nonce_field('update_grn_data','grn_data'); ?>
              <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name="<?php echo $curgrn; ?>" value="<?php echo $grnval; ?>" />
              <input type="submit" value="Save" />
              <?php var_dump($grnval); ?>
              <?php var_dump($curgrn); ?>
          </form>
      </div>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

now call the form

```
echo grn_data($post->ID);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i still see a null value for $grnval. Not getting what went wrong.

Comment: try to pass `$post->ID` in `grn_data($post->ID)` function and add a hidden field to form for `post_id` i am updating the code.

Comment: The problem appears to be something different. I am querying another post type inside a different post type. So the conflict is with the post id's of different types. I now have to figure out a way to solve it. Thanks for your help though.